# Getting stdout from console app asyncronously without waiting for console to exit

Tags: c#, processstartinfo, redirectstandardoutput

I have an issue with getting some console standard output from a small long running console app spawned by my application.

My app starts the console app and the console app will stay alive listening on a port for the duration of my applications lifetime (or until explicitly killed).

When the console app starts, it outputs a port number that it is listening on, I need to asyncronously grab that port number and use it elsewhere in the app. Problem is, my event handler to get the output data is never called. I am sure there must be something trivial I am forgetting to do.

```
  ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
  si.FileName = theFileName;
  si.Arguments = theargs;
  si.UseShellExecute = false;
  si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  si.CreateNoWindow = true;
  _process = Process.Start(si);
  _process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
      //Parse the args.Data string for the port number.
    };
  _process.BeginOutputReadLine(); // My handler never gets called.
  // I don't want to call _process.WaitForExit() here as this is a long running process.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok in my particular case the issue was caused by the console app not flushing stdout.

The console app was written in python (then made runnable in windows by py2exe), it required...

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

To be called before we could get any output prior to app exit.