# Exchanging data between two console applications

Tags: c#

I have 2 console C# applications, for the sake of this example lets call them `app a` and `app b`.

`app a` executes `app b` and passes parameters to it, in turn `app b` processes this information and writes back its responses to console.

I want to know how `app a` can get 'back' these responses, which were written by `app b` into the console?

Comment: you can redirect standard output of one on them. how do you call/start app b from app a ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting stdout from console app asyncronously without waiting for console to exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466873/getting-stdout-from-console-app-asyncronously-without-waiting-for-console-to-exi)

Answer (score 1):

You can use some kind of Interprocess Communication (IPC): shared memory, pipes, sockets etc. A simpler method is to use files, but in this case you have to ensure that only one of the programs access the file at a time (use for example a named mutex).

Comment: If 'app a' uses CreateProcess to start 'app b', then it will have access to its exit code. In some cases this may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this: you could write to a file, for example.

Personally I like anonymous pipes: detail and an example are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WCF over named pipes](http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.nl/2012/02/inter-process-duplex-communication-with.html).

Comment: Dead link. If you elaborate I'll gladly uv